# Android display username after logging in using fragments and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a SQLite database which stores the user details and I want to know how would I display the username after the user has logged in as after logging in I can get it to display the new fragment but on that fragment I want it to display the username of the user that has logged in.

database helper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String LOGIN_TABLE = "login_table";
    public static final String LOGIN_ID = "LOGIN_ID";
    public static final String LOGIN_NAME = "LOGIN_NAME";
    public static final String LOGIN_EMAIL = "LOGIN_EMAIL";
    public static final String LOGIN_PASSWORD = "LOGIN_PASSWORD";
    public static final String LOGIN_CONFIRM = "LOGIN_CONFIRM";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + LOGIN_TABLE + " (LOGIN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,LOGIN_NAME TEXT,LOGIN_EMAIL TEXT,LOGIN_PASSWORD TEXT,LOGIN_CONFIRM TEXT)");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LOGIN_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    
    public boolean insertLoginData(String login_name, String login_email, String login_password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues loginData = new ContentValues();
        loginData.put(LOGIN_NAME, login_name);
        loginData.put(LOGIN_EMAIL, login_email);
        loginData.put(LOGIN_PASSWORD, login_password);
        long result = db.insert(LOGIN_TABLE, null, loginData);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    
    //Registering User
    public Boolean emailcheck(String login_email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + LOGIN_TABLE + " where login_email=?", new String[]{login_email});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    //Logging in user
    public Boolean logincheck(String login_email, String login_password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + LOGIN_TABLE + " where login_email=? and login_password=?", new String[]{login_email, login_password});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Log in class

```
public class AdminFragment extends Fragment {
    private AdminViewModel adminViewModel;
    DatabaseHelper DB_CRIME;
    EditText email,password;
    Button login_btn, register_btn;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        adminViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AdminViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin, container, false);
        
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_admin);
        adminViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        DB_CRIME = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        email = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editText_login_email);
        password = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editText_login_password);
        login_btn = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        register_btn = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String login_email = email.getText().toString();
                String login_password = password.getText().toString();
                Boolean logincheck = DB_CRIME.logincheck(login_email,login_password);

                if(logincheck==true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You have successfully logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerAdmin, new LoggedInFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Details Entered, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerAdmin, new RegisterFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });


        return root;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new method to the DatabaseHelper like this

```
public String getUsernameFromEmail(String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + LOGIN_TABLE + " WHERE " + LOGIN_EMAIL + " = " + email;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    String username = "";
    if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LOGIN_NAME));
    }
    return username;
}
```

Using this method you can fetch the username from your table that belongs to the given email, and because emails are always unique there is no need to check for multiple entries with that email. You can call this method in your desired fragment just like you did for the logincheck, giving you the username as string, after which you can easily display it in a textview for example.

Comment: Could you show me code of how i would show it in my desired fragment

Comment: So in your fragment you can call `String username = DB_CRIME.getUsernameFromEmail(login_email);`. I assume you know how you can then set the text of a TextView with that username string?